# Find recipes that can be cooked from provided ingridients

Tags: algorithm

Sorry for bad English :(

Suppose i can preliminary organize recipes and ingredients data in any way.
How can i effectively conduct search of recipes by user-provided ingredients, preferably sorted by max match - so, first going recipes that use maximum of provided ingridients and do not contain any other ingrs, after them recipes that uses less of provided set and still not any other ingrs, after them recipes with minimum additional requirements and so on?

All i can think about is represent recipe ingridients like bitmasks, and compare required bitmask with all recipes, but it is obviously a bad way to go.

And related things like Levenstein distance i don't see how to use here.

I believe it should be quite common task...

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a homework problem in a data structures or database management class.

Comment: Are you looking for pseudo-code for a general algorithm? What language/technology are you using? If I understand your question correctly, you may want to rewrite your question to: "What algorithm can I implement to find the best matched recipes given a list of ingredients"?

Comment: Atomiton, yes, i could rewrite question that way) I am using perl, SQL, memcached, Redis key-value storage and that algorithm meant to be used on a website.

Comment: John, its not homework problem, and i definetely could solve it with brute-force, but i want to build a fast and scalable solution :-)

Comment: This sounds a bit like a parts-assembly problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about sets - "available ingredients" is one set, and you want to find all recipes whose ingredients form a subset of that, ordered by size. Sets are efficiently implemented as balanced trees or hashtables.

It gets a bit more complicated when you want to address different amounts of ingredients.

**Edit:** If your recipe data is stored in an SQL database, it should actually be possible to do the the whole thing efficiently as an SQL query (which will use hastables and trees internally). But it's going to be a pretty complex query; better ask someone who's better at SQL than me (and of course your actual table structre is necessary).

Comment: Yep, that tasks described via sets pretty well. Lets check that i understand you properly - each recipe have set of ingridients.
How do i build a tree for example, what will be its root, leafs and so on, how i will perform a query?

Comment: @skaurus: the tree only exists to provide log(n) lookup times, so any balanced search tree will do. You shouldn't implement it yourself, there are datastructure libraries for all common languages. If you're using perl, hashes are built into the language.

Comment: i just dont understand, what i going to store in that tree)

Comment: @skaurus: the tree is just a way to implement a set. As I said, you shouldn't work at that level of abstractions. If you're already using SQL, it should be up to the task as well - probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would use a tool like Lucene as it already knows how to do more or less what you need.  Your ingredients would be keywords in the Lucene index and the recipes would be the documents.  You could then search against the Lucene index and it would give you all the matching recipes and can even tell you confidence level.

Lucene is open source with implementations for many languages including .NET, Java, PHP and many others.  See this [link](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) for more info.  There is a link on that page for all the related projects.

Comment: Oh. Or i can use Sphinx, search engine for MySQL... It is definitely a way to go, but i believe that by implementing simpler solution just for this task i can perform better.
Maybe i can google for search engines algorithms and adopt some?

Answer (score 2):

Just for indexing - i am doing some benchmarking, and first approach i've tested - is PostgreSQL realization, using subqueries and intarray type.

So, i have traditional normalized database with tables
**recipes** (id, name, descr), pk(id)
**ingridients** (id, name, descr), pk(id)
**r2i** (recipe_id, ingridient_id), unique(recipe_id, ingridient_id) (seems i dont need that index, its equal to whole table)

name and descr columns filled with some junk just to make tables bigger ;-)
Overall i filled that tables with 200 ingredients, 5000 recipes and each recipe have from 3 to 10 ingredients, overall about 35k rows in r2i.

Suppose i want to search recipes for my ingredient set 129,99,56,180
Query will look like:

```
SELECT recipe_id, recipe_ingrs, icount('{129,99,56,180}'::int[] - recipe_ingrs) as shortage, icount(recipe_ingrs - '{129,99,56,180}'::int[]) as excess
FROM (
  SELECT id as recipe_id, array(select ingridient_id from r2i where r2i.recipe_id = recipes.id)::int[] as recipe_ingrs
  FROM recipes WHERE recipes.id IN (select distinct recipe_id from r2i where ingridient_id IN (129,99,56,180))
) as t
ORDER BY excess ASC, shortage ASC;
```

Query cost about 7k (depends on set you querying for), but on my windows test notebook machine (c2duo, 2gb of ram) it runs very fast - instantly for human eye :)

There is [doc available](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) about intarray type.

Testing not yet completed, i have two more solutions to test, + obtain some numbers about speed.

Comment: Tested two other approaches. One of them Redis, trying to do the job using SINTER, SDIFF - and it is veeeeery slow.  
Other one - Postgres with denormalized table bitrecipes (id int, ingredients int[]) - ingredients field is intarray type.  
And query like  
SELECT id as recipe_id, ingridients,  icount('{129,99,56,180}'::int[] - ingridients) as shortage,  icount(ingridients - '{129,99,56,180}'::int[]) as excess  
FROM bitrecipes  
WHERE ingridients && '{129,99,56,180}'::int[]  
ORDER BY excess ASC, shortage ASC  
have cost just about 100 for 5k rows in table.